# Is the sky on venus likely to be blue above the cloud layer?

Tags: atmosphere, colors, optics

In my sci-if universe, humans are settling in the upper atmosphere of venus, and I was just wondering what kind of view they’d have. According to the Soviet venera probes, the sky on venus is likely to be orange/yellow on the surface due to the high quantities of sulphur in the atmosphere.

However, I can find no source as to the colour of the sky in the *upper* atmosphere, above the supercritical co2 haze and sulphuric acid clouds, where the low pressure and large amounts of nitrogen make it sound almost Earth-like.

So, would the skies of venus *above* the toxic clouds be blue, or no?

Comment: Yes. https://www.rmg.co.uk/stories/topics/why-sky-blue

Comment: @BobaFit's right, but it depends on how thick the upper atmosphere is. Climb to a sufficient altitude in Earth's atmosphere and it'll thin out such that you can see the stars rather than blue sky. It's because there isn't enough atmosphere for an observer to see the effects of Rayleigh Scattering. I don't know how thick the upper atmosphere of Venus is - and that's the datapoint you need to find. Then the question becomes, "If I'm on an inflatable pool chair floating atop the toxic Venus atmosphere, and knowing the atmosphere above me is X km thick with a density of Y, would I see blue?"

Comment: Beware, the second answer to the duplicate is more accurate than the accepted one! (It happens sometimes.)